# Restoring .File Extension SQL Server have empty content

Tags: sql-server, database-restore

Can someone help me restore this backup database?

I backup my database to my D drive it created file with .file extension after that i uninstall my sql server then re install it when i try to restored the database it showed no database.

i ve tried to restore using File and Filegroups but there is no database to select.

this is my file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-VCua2N1hePQjNxa3hCSy0tZjQ/view

it only contain created table  with no data

Answer (score 0):

Run something like this, just specify correct path to a file and where to restore a database:

```
USE [master]
RESTORE DATABASE Test FROM 
DISK = N'D:\....\TreasuryDB' WITH  FILE = 1, NOUNLOAD, 
MOVE N'TreasuryDB' TO N'D:\....\Data\Test.mdf',  
MOVE N'TreasuryDB_log' TO N'D:\....\Log\Testlog.ldf'
```